# Add external data source In Storm

Tags: hadoop, cloud, apache-storm, real-time-data

I am new to Apache Storm. I have currently done word-count problem. Currently my data source (file containing words) is in my local system. But now i need this file to be in external system. i.e. if i tell ip of external system and path to file, then is there way that my application will get data from that file (remotely located)?

Comment: One typical approach is to use a distributed queue, e.g., kafka. You can stream your file onto the queue and have storm read from the queue.

Comment: @lorcan, why don't you put this as an answer?

Comment: may take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510252/how-to-make-my-storm-topology-to-work-real-time/19511569#19511569)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to feed your file to MongoDB and let your spout pull the file from MongoDB.  Have a look at [Storm Mongo](https://github.com/stormprocessor/storm-mongo). But please keep in mind the size of your file.    You don't want to transfer huge files as 'tuples'.